# How to get top n arg max/min in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to get top N arg max/min in tensorflow? 
For top one we have:

```
tf.argmax(input)
```

available at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax

Answer (score 8):

How about this function: [tf.nn.top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) ?

Comment: argmax has axis argument. Looking for the same thing to replace 

    tf.argmax(predict, axis=-1)

with 

    tf.math.top_k(predict, 5, axis=-1)

But top_k doesn't take axis as an argument